# logrotate not working. Is this configuration correct?

Tags: apache-2.2, log-files, logrotate

```
/var/log/apache2/*.log {
        daily
        missingok
        rotate 31
        compress
        delaycompress
        notifempty
        create 640 root adm
        sharedscripts
        postrotate
                if [ -f "`. /etc/apache2/envvars ; echo ${APACHE_PID_FILE:-/var/run/apache2.pid}`" ]; then
                        /etc/init.d/apache2 reload > /dev/null
                fi
        endscript
}

/home/admin/public_html/mywebsite.com/log/*.log {
        daily
        missingok
        rotate 31
        compress
        delaycompress
        missingok
#        notifempty
#        create 640 root adm
        sharedscripts
        postrotate
                if [ -f "`. /etc/apache2/envvars ; echo ${APACHE_PID_FILE:-/var/run/apache2.pid}`" ]; then
                        /etc/init.d/apache2 reload > /dev/null
                fi
        endscript
}
```

This is the exact contents of `apache2` file, minus the fake domain name).

When I logged back into the server after 2 days `access.log` in `mywebsite.com/log` was still multiple gigs.

Is this likely just a `chmod` issue? (I left the commented out lines in my question, just in case they could be the issue.

Comment: It would help if you said exactly *how* it's not working.

Comment: Dennis, the log is still as large as it was 2 days ago (multiple gigs), so I assume it's simply not working at all.

Comment: You can try to manually run logrotate to see if it is really working properly or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try merging the two file lists.

```
/var/log/apache2/*.log /home/admin/public_html/mywebsite.com/log/*.log{
    daily
    missingok
    rotate 31
    compress
    delaycompress
    notifempty
    create 640 root adm
    sharedscripts
    postrotate
            if [ -f "`. /etc/apache2/envvars ; echo ${APACHE_PID_FILE:-/var/run/apache2.pid}`" ]; then
                    /etc/init.d/apache2 reload > /dev/null
            fi
    endscript
```

}

Comment: Why does this work?

Answer (score 2):

logrotate has a really informative man page. For example you could run it in a dry run mode, logrotate would then tell you exactly what it is configured to do, without actually doing it.